# Node.js express passport joi - First validated body/joy or check passport req?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, joi

I have a Node.js express passport joi restful api. When trying to access the routes ... is it better to first validated the inputs (body or query) or check passport requirements?

So this:

```
router.route('/signup')
    .post(validateBody(schemas.signupSchema), passportSignup, controllerSignup.signup);

router.route('/login')
    .post(validateBody(schemas.loginSchema), passportLogin, controllerLogin.login);

router.route('/search')
    .get(validateQuery(schemas.searchSchema), passportJWT, controllerSearch.search);
```

... or this?

```
router.route('/signup')
    .post(passportSignup, validateBody(schemas.signupSchema), controllerSignup.signup);

router.route('/login')
    .post(passportLogin, validateBody(schemas.loginSchema), controllerLogin.login);

router.route('/search')
    .get(passportJWT, validateQuery(schemas.searchSchema), controllerSearch.search);
```

Which version is preferred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really matter as, both of them are middlewares, doesn't matter which one fails first. But, doing passport authentication first is a better idea cause, why even process the data if the user isn't correctly authenticated.